# how to display all categories on template in django

Tags: python, django, web

I was trying to fetch all the categories on the template but they are repeating because there are multiple lines in database.
[here is what currently showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcABH.png)

Comment: You'll need to add the relevant view and template to the question for people to help

Comment: Can you please add the code? It will be much easier to troubleshoot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `distinct` from  Django ORM can help:

```
your_category_queryset = your_category_queryset.distinct()
```

or, in template:

```
{% for category in your_category_queryset.distinct %} 
    {{ category }}
{% endfor %}
```

More here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I can't see your codes. So here is an example to solve your problem.

model:

```
class Category (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

view:

```
def category(request):
categories = Category.objects.all()
context =  {'categories': categories}
return render (request, 'index.html', context)
```

index.html:

```
 <h3>Catagory:</h3>
      <ul>
        {% for category in categories %}
        <li>
            {{category.name}}
          </a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
```